# What's a proper way to cut out simple windows?

Tags: modeling

I'm just trying to cut out very basic windows that are good enough for a simple low poly game. My friend is making for fun, these buildings can literally be rectangles with the boolean modifier cutting out rectangles for windows. But I was told recently the boolean modifier leaves a mess of ngons which are bad for games. Therefore I'm wondering what's the proper way? Or should I be using geometry nodes to simplify this?

Comment: If your object is simple rectangles, just use inset (shortcut i), resize, and delete the center face

Comment: Really wish it were that simple of a building I kinda need multiple windows atleast 4. But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes what I do is add *Loop Cuts* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (using scroll wheel to add or subtract loops) until I have enough 'wall panels' to do what I want.  You can technically build a cleaner topology, but it shouldn't be too demanding in terms of excess polygons.

Use *Delete* <kbd>X</kbd> -> *Only Faces*

[image]

Comment: This gif is terrible, I messed my settings up somehow.  Sorry lol

Comment: More than close enough. Eventually I stopped anticipating it being answered. But this gives me a better idea. Thanks!